# How can I pass arrays to functions in zsh similar to using namerefs in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

I switched my code from bash to zsh for the decimal feature.

I am trying to use namerefs to pass arrays to a function but recieve the error `bad option: -n`. The code shown below works for bash but not zsh.

An example of what I am doing is below

```
foo(){
    local -n _array1=$1
    local -n _array2=$2
    echo ${_array2[@]}, ${_array2[@]}
}
main(){
    local array1=(1 1 1 1)
    local array2=(2 2 2 2)
    foo array1 array2
}

main
```

How can I pass both arrays to the function when using zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, you have to use the `(P)` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) instead.

> This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a further parameter name, whose value will be used where appropriate.

Example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

demo() {
    printf "%s\n" "${(P)1[@]}"
}

arr=(1 2 3 4 5)
demo arr
```